# Telnet memchached stats- number of keys read in a time duration

Tags: memcached, telnet

Is it possible to connect to memcached server using telnet and fetch the number of keys read in last 24 hours ( or any time duration)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The standard memcached server doesn't provide that information out of the box. It's easy enough to regularly interrogate the daemon and store any/all the relevant information, in order to produce stats and graphs. An easy example of that is is shown by scripts such as [memcache-stats.sh](https://gist.github.com/danielbeardsley/3235099).